# Use of the pseudo-noun 한

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

So, this word, according to some Korean grammar books, means "situation", and is similar to 경우, as in this:

... 법과 어긋나지 않는 한 기꺼이 양보합니다

However I am not sure when exactly this word is used, and its meaning too.

Much help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you quote a sentence in the book? The sentence doesn't make sense. And what do you mean by "pseudo-noun"? Did you hear this term used?

Comment: By pseudo-noun, I think they mean 의존명사,  but it's usually translated as 'dependent noun' - a noun that can't be used in any way, only within a particular syntactic structure, in this case after a present participle -는.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, as a native speaker of the language, '-한' is often used. But it's not something that can be written by itself. It's similar to 'as long as'.

> 법과 어긋나지 않는 한 기꺼이 양보합니다.

Therefore, the above sentence would mean

> As long as it does not violate the law, we will willingly yield.

Another example:

> 그들이 항복하지 않는 한 우리는 계속 공격할 것입니다.
>
> As long as they don't surrender, we will keep attacking them.

Comment: OK so can you give some examples on how this one is used as the meaning of “as long as”?

Comment: 그들이 항복하지 않는 한 우리는 계속 공격할 것입니다

Comment: Meaning, as long as they don't surrender, we will keep attacking them

Comment: Hello Danny Han. Welcome to Korean Stack Exchange. Please check the edit I made and see what has been changed by clicking on "edited X min ago" above my user name.